# sending email using php

Tags: php, email, drupal

I am working on a drupal site.I add a mail functionality to that site using php mail function and I used mozilla thunderberd for finding that email sending work properly.some time mailing is work correctly.but sometime it is not working at all without changing the code anyway.below is the code I used for sending email.

```
 $success = mail('lakshman@codegen.net','hi',$message);
            if($success){
                print "email send successfully";
            }else{
                print "email sending failed";   
            }
```

I used ajax reqest to fire this mail function using mootools.here is the code for that

```
$('emailButton').addEvent('click', function(event) {
    alert("hi I am here");
    event.stop();
    var hello = 'hello world.......!';
    var req = new Request({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'mail.php',
            data: { 'hello' : hello },
            onRequest: function() { alert('The request has been made, please wait until it has finished.'); },
            onComplete: function(response) { alert('The response is the following : ' + response); }
                }).send();
            });
```

is there any reason for that not working and working for same code?

Answer (score 2):

You can add header in `mail()` .. like this

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "From: $sFrom <ADMIN MAIL ID>\r\n";
$headers .= "To: $to\r\n";
```

header is not included in your mail function that can be reason that sometimes it gives an warning or errors...

Answer (score 1):

You should use [drupal_mail](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--mail.inc/function/drupal_mail/7) function, as it takes care of headers for you.

P.S. : also, it is best practices to use [Drupal's built-in jQuery behaviors](http://drupal.org/node/305747).